# Is it possible to check (prevent to display) value for decimal length before show it in input field?

Tags: javascript, regex

We have same input tag, and event listener for checking user's input, we accept just numbers, float and integer and if it's float - we need to show just 2 decimal digits after coma or point.And we just want to prevent type 3rd decimal, but accept changing integer part for our value.

No visible replacing, no changing after blur.Just preventing 3rd decimal digit when typing.

Comment: @richardnelson That won't prevent the typing of a 3rd decimal. This is a question about input, not output.

Comment: richard nelson, without rounding, prevent typing next digit

Comment: @richardnelson Again, that won't prevent bad input. It will just validate it. The OP wants to prevent a 3rd digit from being entered.

Comment: @richardnelson Yes, but it should be the `input` or a `key` event, not `change` as you have to leave the field for `change` to fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Maybe will be useful for someone, someday!

**selector** - target input

**n** - number of signs after coma

```js
function floatRestriction(selector, n){

        var targetElement = document.querySelector(selector);
        var oldValue = '';
        var regexValue = '^([0-9]+[\,\.]{1}[0-9]{0,'+n+'}|[0-9]+|)$';
        var re = new RegExp(regexValue);

       targetElement.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
            oldValue = event.target.value;      
       });

       targetElement.addEventListener('input', function(event){

            if(!re.test(event.target.value)){
            event.target.value = oldValue || '';
            }
      });

    }
    
floatRestriction('#someInput', 2);
```

```html
    <input type="input" id="someInput">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the input for the occurence of a dot.

In case there is, compare it's position to the length of the string and if it exceeds the number of digits you want, cut the rest off.

```js
document.getElementById("theInput").addEventListener("input", process);

function process() {
  var text = document.getElementById("theInput").value;
  var index = text.indexOf(".");
  if (index > -1) {
    if (text.length - index > 3) {
      document.getElementById("theInput").value = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="input" id="theInput">
```

Comment: No need to convert a form field value into a string. Everything in HTML is already a string.

Comment: Yeah, that's true Scott. I've removed the unnecessary conversion.